# Как запросить разрешение у пользователя на отображение уведомлений в Android 13, Xamarin?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

В моем приложении необходимы уведомления, они работали без разрешений на android 11 и ниже, у меня в пользовании есть телефон с `android 13`. На официальном сайте `Android develop`, нашла , что нужно было прописать в manifest.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
```

После этого появилась возможность зайти самостоятельно в настройки и поставить галочку включить уведомления. Но остается вопрос как вызвать Alert, для запроса разрешения. Вот пример того самого алерта.

[image: Пример уведомления]

Кроме этого уведомления , на данный момент я запрашиваю на микрофон и хранилище (они работают ). Вот их Код

```
public static async Task Permission()
        {
            // Даю разрешения для микрофона и (зписи/чтения файлов)
            var PermissionsStrorage_Write = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.StorageWrite>();

            var PermissionsInternet = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.NetworkState>();

            var PermissionsStrorage_Read = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.StorageRead>();

            var PermissionsRecord = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.Microphone>();
            if (PermissionsInternet != PermissionStatus.Granted)
            {
                PermissionsInternet = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.NetworkState>();

            }
            // 
            // Прверка разрешенний
            if (PermissionsRecord != PermissionStatus.Granted)
            {
                PermissionsRecord = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.Microphone>();

            }
            // Прверка разрешенний
            if (PermissionsStrorage_Write != PermissionStatus.Granted && PermissionsStrorage_Read != PermissionStatus.Granted)
            {
                PermissionsStrorage_Write = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.StorageWrite>();
                PermissionsStrorage_Read = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.StorageRead>();
            }
            if (PermissionsStrorage_Write != PermissionStatus.Granted && PermissionsStrorage_Read != PermissionStatus.Granted)
            {
                return;
            }
        }
```

Comment: targerSdk поменяли на 33 (Android 13)? https://stackoverflow.com/a/74220136/5479247

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, Да конечно , буквально 10 минут назад, решение нашлось , скоро опубликую

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение:

Первым делом необходимо понять на какой платформе необходимо запускать разрешение (Android, Ios). В коде выше была попытка запустить разрешение из Общего проекта Xamarin.Forms. Это действительно работает, при помощи библиотеки `Xamarin.Essentials`, но скорее всего ее не обновляют или она предоставляет мало функционала. Т.К при пользовании данной библиотекой не было возможности вызвать разрешение `PostNotifications`. В данный момент мне нужно было вызывать разрешение на проекте Android. поэтому переходим в проект Xamarin.Android. и перед запуском программы или там где вам удобно добавляем код:

```
var thisActivity = Forms.Context as Activity;
ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(thisActivity, new string[] {
Manifest.Permission.PostNotifications,
Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage,
Manifest.Permission.RecordAudio }, 1);
```

Тут мы создаем тот сам алерт , Метод `RequestPermissions()` его вызывает, туда мы как раз и передаем те разрешения которые нам нужны (массив `string[]`).

Естественно перед использование каких либо разрешений, требуется указать их в манифесте. Вот запись в манифесте для уведомлений:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
```

Есть одна особенность, это если пользователь запретил, то повторный раз это окно не появится , даже в некоторых приложениях после этого высвечивается подсказка, что надо включить это в настройках.
Да и вот так можно проверить включено разрешение или нет:

```
var Grant = ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(Android.App.Application.Context, Manifest.Permission.PostNotifications);
```